# How to transform a string into a variable/field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I would like to find out what the best way of doing things is.

Assume the following scenario:

I have a text field where the user can input strings. Based on what the user inputs (after validation) I would like to access different fields of an instance variable.

Example: `@zoo` is an instance variable. The user inputs `"monkey"` and I would like to access `@zoo.monkey`. How can I do that in Ruby?

One idea that crossed my mind is to have a hash:

```
zoo_hash = { "monkey" => @zoo.monkey, ... }
```

but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your controller you could use the `public_send` (or even `send`) method like this:

```
def your_action
  @zoo.public_send(params[:your_field])
end
```

Obviously this is **no** good, since someone can post somehing like `delete_all` as the method name, so you must sanitize the value you get from the form. As a simple example:

```
ALLOWED_METHODS = [:monkey, :tiger]

def your_action
  raise unless ALLOWED_METHODS.include?(params[:your_field])
  @zoo.public_send(params[:your_field])
end
```

Comment: The problem here is maintaining the ALLOWED_METHOD constant. That's technical debt.

Comment: The edit does solve the problem of safe methods, but why bother when you can specifically target attributes?

Answer (score 3):

`@zoo.attributes` gives you a hash of the object attributes. So you can access them like

```
@zoo.attributes['monkey']
```

This will give `nil` if the attribute is not present. Calling a method which doesn't exist will throw `NoMethodError`

Comment: +1: This is safer and more maintainable than a `send` approach

Comment: It would be neat if this were true, but it isn't in any release of Ruby I'm aware of.  Maybe this is a Rails thing?

Comment: Ah, I did just notice the [tag:ruby-on-rails] tag, so maybe that's okay.

Comment: You can use `instance_variable_get`, it's vanilla ruby.

Answer (score 2):

There is much better way to do this - you should use Object#send or (even better, because it raises error if you try to call private or protected method) Object#public_send, like this:

```
message = 'monkey'
@zoo.public_send( message )
```

Comment: This is dangerous, see toro2k's answer.

Comment: rmihalyi didn't say the @zoo was an ActiveRecord object. :)

Comment: We're talking about fields and attributes, not sending any message to an object, especially if the message comes from the user! How about `instance_eval { system "ifconfig" }` ? shell access!

Comment: I'm not defending my answer here. It's incomplete indeed, it shows only the way to achieve the target, not full implementation. Should I delete it, since there are more complete answers?

Comment: It's ok, it informs about a pitfall. You should leave it I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `method_missing` in your class and have it interrogate `@zoo` for a matching method. Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing

```
require 'ostruct' # only necessary for my example

class ZooKeeper

  def initialize
    @zoo = OpenStruct.new(monkey: 'chimp')
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    if @zoo.respond_to?(method)
      return @zoo.send(method)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

keeper = ZooKeeper.new
keeper.monkey  #=> "chimp"
keeper.lion    #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `lion'
```